# How do I add variables to a velcoity template JIRA page?

Tags: jira

I am looking to capture values from the 'affected version' field of New Bug screen along with the project name and dynamically add these values to the table in my new screen, which was created using a velocity template. I have recently checkout an uploaded the plugin ***WebWork tutorial*** plugin but I am having difficulty working out how to utilise this as I very new to JIRA.

As always grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The base class for all custom fields in JIRA is

http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/issue/customfields/CustomFieldType.html

and it has a method getVelocityParameters that can be used to add variables to the context used in velocity templates, e.g. $mynewvariable. I'd suggest poking around the source looking at some of the CFType.java files for examples of how this can work.

~Matt